# Best container combination to hold named set of coordinates

Tags: c++, optimization, containers

I need to hold a set of up to 50 coordinate (x, y) sets, up to 4 each, so it would look like:

> ```
> 4: {7, 3}, {5, 3}
> 27: {1, 1}
> 44: {9, 9}, {9, 7}, {7, 7} and so on
> ```

Both x and y will never be higher than 9 nor lower than 0. I ended up with `unordered_map<uint8_t, vector<vector<uint8_t>>>`, but almost sure that its inefficient. Also, it will be generated over a cycle with a bunch of `if`'s and deleted after few reads.

Comment: *best* is really going to depend on your use case.  Without knowing that it's hard to recommend anything beside a vector.

Comment: unordered_map<uint8_t, vector<pair<uint8_t, uint8_t>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about x and y (0 <= x <= 9), you can use [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

And I would store data like this

```
struct Pair {
  uint8_t x:4;
  uint8_t y:4;
};

unordered_map<uint8_t, vector<Pair>> container;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a multidimensional vector, as such:

`vector <pair<int, int>> coordinates[50];`

What this declaration does it it declares an `array` of 50 `vectors` containing `pairs of integers`. The pairs of integers would represent an x and a y-coordinate in your case.

Comment: As I said, I need to name (or give a key to) these coordinates and the case where it will use at least 25 is very rare so allocating 50 every time is bad also bc it could be done thousands of times at regular basis.